# Groovy cliBuilder class not exists

Tags: groovy

I have download apache-groovy-sdk-4.0.5.zip, and moved file location into /usr/share/groovy

```
pwd
/usr/share/groovy
export GROOVY_HOME=/usr/share/groovy
PATH="$GROOVY_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

[root@devops groovy]# groovy -v
Groovy Version: 4.0.5 JVM: 1.8.0_342 Vendor: Red Hat, Inc. OS: Linux
[root@devops groovy]#
[root@devops groovy]#
[root@devops groovy]#
[root@devops groovy]# whereis groovy
groovy: /home/user/team/groovy-4.0.5/bin/groovy.ico /home/user/team/groovy-4.0.5/bin/groovy /home/user/team/groovy-4.0.5/bin/groovy.bat
```

when i running my groovy script i'm getting error like unable to resolve class CliBuilder

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/media/data1/wm10/abe/groovy/CreateProjectAutomatorTemplate.groovy: 9: unable to resolve class CliBuilder
 @ line 9, column 11.
   def cli = new CliBuilder (usage:'createProjectAutomater.groovy [options]')
             ^

/media/data1/wm10/abe/groovy/CreateProjectAutomatorTemplate.groovy: 89: unable to resolve class XmlSlurper
 @ line 89, column 32.
           def componentFileXml = new XmlSlurper().parse(componentsFile)
```

Comment: Have you imported the class to your script? `import groovy.cli.commons.CliBuilder`

Comment: Hi @ Mike after adding import statement CliBuilder error is resolved. 
But unable to resolve class XmlSlurper error is persists

Comment: `import groovy.json.JsonSlurper`, are you using an IDE? you'll get warnings and assistance with stuff like imports in the editor with something like intellij IDEA community edition.

Comment: Thanks again Mike, I'm not using any IDE, just using it inside the Linux box, i have only one script to create some project it's given by webmethod sag team.

Comment: It's working now as per your given input, thanks for your time and support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem trying to compile a Gradle project that referenced `groovy.cli.commons.CliBuilder`. The import was added correctly, however the class was not found:

```
script.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class groovy.cli.commons.CliBuilder
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import groovy.cli.commons.CliBuilder
   ^

1 error
```

The gradle dependencies looked like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.8'
}
```

The solution was to import `groovy.cli.picocli.CliBuilder` instead of `groovy.cli.commons.CliBuilder`. It seems that with Groovy 4.0.8 `groovy.cli.commons.CliBuilder` is no longer contained in the `groovy-all` JAR. The new package seems to be similar in terms of functionality, so replacing the import was enough.

See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.groovy/groovy-all/4.0.8 -> Compile Dependencies

Also see https://github.com/remkop/picocli and https://blogs.apache.org/logging/entry/groovy-2-5-clibuilder-renewal